# Collective name and new question count overlaps

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

If the Collective name is too long it overlaps with the new contents count. Not a big issue but I feel a truncation would be better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for flagging this. The issue is known to us and we have a solution we'll be implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, the collective name will now wrap to a second line when needed.